# SetResult() back to calling activity in DEEP LINKING?

Tags: android, deep-linking

I am implementing DeepLinking in my Android Application. Suppose I am making a payment using PhonePe and choose pay using other Application and select my Application.

```
Intent intent = new Intent().
intent.setData("the data");
startactivityforresult(intent, 111);
```

Then user selects my Application and My Splash screen then I go to other activity like this

```
Intent i = new Intent(Splashscreen.this, FirstActivity.class);
startactivity(i);
finish();
```

Then to Other Activity like this -

```
Intent i2 = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startactivity(i2);
finish();
```

And After some time in SecondActivity, I send back the result to the calling activity or here the PhonePe like this -

```
Intent backintent = new Intent();
backintent.putExtra("somekey", "somevalue");
setResult(Result.OK, backintent);
```

Now when my Application closes and gets back to the Phoneme the data received by Phonepe is null.

However, if I am doing the same thing with other Application which has only one activity the data captured by the calling activity is not null and working fine.

I want to know how to send the data back to the calling activity.
I am able to send the data if its only inside the **same Application**.

Do I have to use other tags while starting an activity?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to also start any new activity with `startActivityForResult` method then pass result back with a chain of `setResult` calls, getting it inside `onActivityResult` and setting again with `setResult`.

Comment: So according to my ques, I should also startactivityforResult() when going from first to second Activity and in FirstActviity's onActvitiyResult, I need to again setResult() then only the data can be passed without being null

Comment: Yes, you should pass data this way back from newly created activities to originally started one.

Comment: One More question Anton, In order to get the data back to the calling activity I should not finish the activity because the onactvitiyResult() of that particular activity will never get called and I won't be able to send back the result in onActivityResult().

Comment: Yes, you have to keep originally started activity running

Answer (score 5):

More detailed description

We have to start activity as `startActivityForResult`. As name suggest you that it will return you some kind of result. This result will be come from another activity which you launch from here.

Eg : **MainActivity class**

```
   Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);  
            startActivityForResult(intent, 2);// Activity is started with requestCode 2
```

Get the result like that inside `onActivityResult` method.

```
// Call Back method  to get the Message form other Activity  
    @Override  
       protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  
       {  
                 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
                  // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2  
                   if(requestCode==2)  
                         {  
                            String message=data.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");   
                            textView1.setText(message);  
                         }
```

**SecondActivity class**

Send result from this activity to previous activity which you launch.

```
  Intent intent=new Intent();  
                intent.putExtra("MESSAGE", "your message");  
                setResult(2,intent);  
                finish();//finishing activity
```

Answer (score 3):

You can only send result back to activity where the **startActivityForResult**
called 
In your case the follow like this

> PhonePe Activity -> Splash Activity -> 2nd Activity -> PhonePe Activity

One StartActivityForResult is not enough for your case, because the PhonePe call your splash activity if you want to send back data you must send it from splash activity, not from 2nd activity

**OR Use this trick**

> PhonePe Activity <-> Splash Activity <-> 2nd Activity

1. When you get call from PhonePe start 2nd Activity for result
2. When on 2 activity complete send the result back to Splash Activity
3. When you get result from 2nd activity on Splash activity send result back to PhonePe

**Some codes**
Start SecondActivity from splash activity

```
Intent intent=new Intent(SplashActivity.this,SecoundActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("SomeKey","SomeValue");
    startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE);
```

Handle result on Splash Activity

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    setResult(requestCode,data);
}
```

On your second activity for send back result 

*if operation completed*

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,data);
```

*If operation failed*

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED,data);
```

> **Note**
>
> 2nd Activity send result back to splash Activity, and the same result send back to PhonePe from Splash Activity

Answer (score -1):

Change `startActivityForResult` to `onActivityResult`.